# removing characters like '\u0152\xe6' from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am trying to convert a string just with English characters, numbers and punctuations but facing an error with encoding and decoding.

The original string is: "DD-XBS 2 1/2x 17 LCLŒæ 3-pack"

The code I wrote to tackle this issue is:

```
try:
    each = str(each.decode('ascii'))
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    each = str(each.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

but I am getting an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 16: invalid start byte
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I tried your code in ipython, not getting any error.

Comment: @pnv python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: i used python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it follows from your question, I assume that you use Python 2.7.

The **reason** of the error is:

1. Your source code is not in UTF-8 and almost certainly in cp1252.

   In cp1252 the 'Œ' character is the byte '\x8c', and that byte is not valid in UTF-8.

   You specified UTF-8 as the encoding to decode your string in 'except' part.

For better understanding look at that:

```
>>> u = '\x8c'.decode('cp1252')
>>> u
u'\u0152'
```

So, when we decode '\x8c' byte with cp1252, there is the Unicode code point, which is:

```
>>> import unicodedata 
>>> unicodedata.name(u)
'LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE'
```

However, if we try to decode with UTF-8, we'll get an error:

```
>>> u = '\x8c'.decode('utf-8')
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c ...
```

So, '\x8c' byte and UTF-8 encoding are incompatible. 

**To fix** the problem you can try this:

```
each = str(each.decode('cp1252').encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

Or this:

```
each = str(each.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

Also in your case you can use ord():

```
my_str = 'DD-XBS 2 1/2x 17 LCLŒæ 3-pack'
ascii_str = ''

for sign in my_str:
    if ord(sign) < 128:
        ascii_str += sign

print(ascii_str) # DD-XBS 2 1/2x 17 LCL 3-pack
```

But possibly the best solution is just to convert your source to UTF-8.

Comment: Just one question. How did you identified that its encoding as 'cp1252'? Is there any method available for this?

Comment: From the error report and 'Œ' char view I guessed that the actual encoding is one of the most common Western Europe encodings. 
Then I checked how '\x8c' byte will look after decoding in cp1252, latin_1 and mac_roman - by using `print('\x8c'.decode('cp1252'))` and so on. 
And only cp1252-decoded view matched.
So, to detect the right encoding, when we have a char view and its byte value, I suggest to make a list of possible encodings and print decoded byte in a loop via that list. Also, If somehow we know Unicode code point of the char, we can avoid print and break the loop after mathing.